# Handling button clicks in Jquery mobile and Ajax

Tags: jquery, html

Hi guys i'm using this code to load a page in a div(`#content`) and be able to click on links in the loaded page:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "new_pm.php"
}).done(function(data) {
    $("#content").html(data);
});



$("#content").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var html = this.href;
    $("#content").load(html)
});
```

This works perfectly so when I click on links a new page loads.

The problem is that there is a `submit` button in the page and when I click on it nothing happens when it is supposed to load a new page. (the button works when I load the page separately , I mean outside the div)

I tried this but does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#submit').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

      var html = this.href;
      $("#content").load(html)
  });
});
```

Comment: there is `on` method, check the docs

Comment: Which version of `jQuery` are you using?

Comment: The problem is that you js loads prior to the pages that are then being loaded in, s there 'Submit' code has nothing to bind on when initially loaded, and when you load the internal pages it wont then bind to it, you would need to re-init the button code after the page load so that the button code then can link to the new page loaded

Comment: I think you are right but can you tell me how to do that , i mean re-init the button code after the page load